# How to schedule background services while an iOS app is closed?

Tags: ios, iphone, background-fetch

I am working on an app that keeps people updated with news around a certain event. That means that I don't want to run background fetches all the time. And one more thing, what I understood from Apple's [background execution documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) is that it is not guarantee to have those fetch operations scheduled as the minimum fetch interval set.

So is there any way to schedule those fetches guaranteeing those fetch intervals? I know of silent push notifications but I don't want to have a server side solution.

Comment: Maybe someone else can help you, but as far as I know the only way to trigger a content update for your app, while closed, is using silent notifications.  You might be able to get away with local notifications, but i'm 90% sure they will not fire if your app is terminated.

Comment: Local notifications AFAIK can't be treated silently and you need the user to interact with them so you get the handler in the app delegate. :/